# Enviar el contenido de un archivo .eml por email con c#

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2015

¿Sería posible enviar el contenido de un archivo .eml por email con c# sin archivo adjunto?

Actualmente envío mensajes con la clase `MailMessage` y no se si sería posible introducir en el messaje el contenido (con fotografías incluidas) del archivo .eml.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar [Chilkat Email .NET Component](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-dotnet.asp)

Tiene un metodo `LoadEml` donde solo pasas la ruta de tu archivo

[Documentación](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csEmailRef.html):

> ```
> public bool LoadEml(string mimePath);
> ```
>
> Loads a complete email from a .EML file. (EML files are simply RFC822 MIME text files.)
>
> Returns true for success, false for failure.

Answer (score 3):

Podrias evaluar alguna libreria que implemente un eml reader, como ser

[Easily Retrieve Email Information from .EML Files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76607/Easily-Retrieve-Email-Information-from-EML-Files-R)

[Advanced MIME Parser/Creator/Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11882/Advanced-MIME-Parser-Creator-Editor)

Para asi poder extraer la informacion del eml y usar esto en el armado del MailMessage

---

Tambien hay algunos viewer, de los cuales tener el codigo y analizar como parsean el eml, tomarias esas partes para armar tu propia utilidad.

[Desktop Eml (Eml) Viewer](https://tciemlreader.codeplex.com/)